# Azure Logic App, parse JSON, but possible null

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to parse json, based on the following classes:

```
public class DerModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class DriverPositiveResultModel
{
    public int DriverId { get; set; }
    public string DriverName { get; set; }
    public string DriverSSN { get; set; }
    public string CarrierName { get; set; }
    public DerModel DER { get; set; }
}
```

and the following schema:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "CarrierName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "DER": {
            "properties": {
                "Email": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Name": {
                    "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "type": "object"
    },
    "DriverId": {
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "DriverName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "DriverSSN": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"type": "object"
```

}

but logic allows, that DER can be null. How to set it in the schema?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify that it can be null:

```
"type": ["object","null"]
```

so your code would look like this:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "CarrierName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "DER": {
            "properties": {
                "Email": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Name": {
                    "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "type": ["object","null"]
    },
    "DriverId": {
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "DriverName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "DriverSSN": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"type": "object"
}
```